# Transformations of circular functions: finding parameters from two graphs

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[image]

I solved part (e) of this question and found $K = 4$, $p = \pi/8$ and $q = -2$.
I am unsure if these answers are correct. Could someone please check and let me know if I am on the right track. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period of $S(x) = \frac {\pi}{2}$
The period of $C(x) = \pi$

The horizontal stretch is $2.$

If we stretch before we translate the horizontal shift will be doubled. $\frac {\pi}{4}$

And, yes, the vertical shift is -2.

Comment: Thanks Doug M, could you please clarify your third statement, I am a bit confused. What is the meaning of pi/4?

Comment: $p = \frac {\pi}{4}$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks.